# How to convert TJsonString into string containing JSON?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe6

Give a **TJsonString** object, how can I get a string representation of the JSON?

Given the following example (valid) JSON:

```json
{
   "comment":"The quick bröwn fox\r\n\tjumped \"over\" the \\lazy\/ dog\r\nthen  on a log."
}
```

In readable text, the `comment` would look like:

```
The quick bröwn fox  
    jumped "over" the \lazy/ dog  
then  on a log.
```

We parse this JSON into an object:

```pascal
o: TJsonObject;
o := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonStr), 0, True) as TJsonObject;
```

We have a JSON object in memory. Now our goal is to convert it into JSON.

How do I have Delphi XE6 return me the corresponding valid JSON string?

## Research Effort

### Attempt #1 - `TJsonObject.ToString()`

The call:

```pascal
o.ToString
```

returns the (invalid) JSON:

```json
{"comment":"The quick bröwn fox↵
    jumped \"over\" the \lazy/ dog↵
then  on a log."}
```

The JSON is invalid because:

- it isn't escaping `CR` into `\r`
- it isn't escaping `LF` into `\n`
- it isn't escaping `\` into `\\`
- it isn't escaping `/` into `\/`

This makes sense because `ToString()` is meant to [return human-readable text; not valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51237438/12597)

### Attempt #2 - `TJsonObject.ToJson()`

While `ToString()` is meant to return human-readable text, [`ToJSON()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.ToJSON) is meant to return valid JSON.

The only problem is that it doesn't exist in Delphi XE6.

Moving on!

### Attempt #3 - `TJsonObject.ToBytes()`

Populate a byte array using the `ToBytes()` method:

```pascal
// Allocate a buffer to hold the JSON
buffer: TBytes;
SetLength(buffer, o.EstimatedByteSize);

// Populate the buffer, and size it to its actual length
n: Integer;
n := o.ToBytes(buffer, 0);  // fill the byte array buffer
SetLength(buffer, n);       // size buffer to final size

// Copy byte array to RawByteString so we can see it
s: RawByteString; 
SetLength(s, n);            // size the raw byte string
Move(buffer[0], s[1], n);   // fill the raw byte string
```

returns the following JSON:

```json
{"comment":"The quick br\u00F6wn fox\r\n\tjumped \"over\" the \\lazy\/ dog\r\nthen \uD83D\uDCA9 on a log."}
```

While that does *technically* generate valid JSON, it's needlessly escaping any code point above #127. Not ideal, and not what I wanted, not what I'm asking for, since strings in JSON **are** allowed to contain "Unicode characters".

And, to fix it all, I'd have to do is: write a JSON parser, and then code to convert JSON to string. Which is the question I'm asking.

### Attempt #4 - Fixup `ToString()`

Knowing that `TJsonString.ToString()` will return a string that is **almost** valid JSON:

```
"The quick bröwn fox#$D#$A
#9'jumped \"over\" the lazy dog#$D#$A
then  on a log."
```

I can see that it's *pretty close* to being valid JSON. We just have to apply ***some*** JSON escaping rules:

- #$D -> `\r`
- #$A -> `\n`
- #$9 -> `\t`
- `\` -> `leave as-is`
- `"` -> `leave as-is`
- `/` -> `leave as-is`

But I don't know what happens with other control characters under #32.

### Attempt #5 - Access `TJsonString`'s protected `TStringBuilder`

The object maintains a protected buffer of the actual *characters* in the json:

```pascal
  TJSONString = class(TJSONValue)
  protected
    FStrBuffer: TStringBuilder;
```

And these characters are the actual characters they should be in-memory:

```
'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'b', 'r', 'ö', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'x', #$D, #$A, 
#9, 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 'e', 'd', ' ', '"', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', '"', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', '\', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', '/', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g', #$D, #$A, 
't', 'h', 'e', 'n', ' ', #$D83D, '�', ' ', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'g', '.', #0
```

So, if I can reach inside the `TJsonString`, I can suck out the *correct* characters:

```pascal
type
  TJsonStringFriend = class(TJsonString);

var
  s: UnicodeString;

s := TJsonStringFriend(AJsonString).FStrBuffer.ToString;
```

Which returns exactly what a `UnicodeString` of the string should contain:

```
The quick bröwn fox'#$D#$A#9'jumped "over" the \lazy/ dog'#$D#$A'then  on a log.
```

Now, all I have to do is escape the string back into JSON:

```pascal
var
  i: Integer;
  ch: WideChar;
   
for i := 1 to Length(s) do
begin
  ch := s[i];
  case ch of
    '"': Result := Result + '\"';
    '\': Result := Result + '\\';
    '/': Result := Result + '\/';
    #$8: Result := Result + '\b';
    #$c: Result := Result + '\f';
    #$a: Result := Result + '\n';
    #$d: Result := Result + '\r';
    #$9: Result := Result + '\t';
    else
      if (ch < WideChar(32)) then
        Result := Result + '\u'+IntToHex(Ord(ch), 4)
      else
        Result := Result + ch;
  end;
end;
```

But, in order to use that, we have to do *everything*:

```pascal
function JsonValueToJSON(JsonValue: TJSONValue; Indentation: string=''): UnicodeString;
var
  jsonArray: TJSONArray;
  jsonObject: TJSONObject;
  pair: TJSONPair;
  i: Integer;
  s: UnicodeString;
  ch: WideChar;
begin
  if JsonValue is TJSONArray then
  begin
    jsonArray := JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    Result := '[' + sLineBreak;
    for i := 0 to jsonArray.Count-1 do
    begin
      Result := Result + Indentation + '    ' + JsonValueToJSON(jsonArray.Items[i], Indentation + ' ');
      if i < jsonArray.Count-1 then
        Result := Result + ',';
      Result := Result + sLineBreak;
    end;
    Result := Result + Indentation + ']';
  end
  else if JsonValue is TJSONObject then
  begin
    jsonObject := JsonValue as TJSONObject;
    Result := '{' + sLineBreak;
    for i := 0 to jsonObject.Count-1 do
    begin
      pair := jsonObject.Pairs[i];
      Result := Result + Indentation+'  "'+pair.JsonString.Value+'": '+JsonValueToJSON(pair.JsonValue, Indentation+ '   ');
      if i < jsonObject.Count-1 then
        Result := Result + ',';
      Result := Result + sLineBreak;
    end;
    Result := Result + Indentation + '}';
  end
  else if JsonValue is TJsonString then
  begin
    // Delphi doesn't know how to emit valid JSON; we'll do it ourselves
    Result := '"';
    //s := (JsonValue as TJsonString).ToString;
    s := TJsonStringFriend(JsonValue as TJsonString).FStrBuffer.ToString;
    for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    begin
      ch := s[i];
      case ch of
        '"': Result := Result + '\"';
        '\': Result := Result + '\\';
        '/': Result := Result + '\/';
        #$8: Result := Result + '\b';
        #$c: Result := Result + '\f';
        #$a: Result := Result + '\n';
        #$d: Result := Result + '\r';
        #$9: Result := Result + '\t';
        else
          if (ch < WideChar(32)) then
            Result := Result + '\u'+IntToHex(Ord(ch), 4)
          else
            Result := Result + ch;
      end;
    end;
    Result := Result+'"';
  end
  else
  begin
    // JsonValue is TJSONNumber, TJSONTrue, TJSONFalse, TJSONNull
    // I trust those know how to serialize themselves correctly into JSON
    Result := JsonValue.ToString;
  end;
end;
```

Except, now I'm in a situation where I *hope* I got it all correct.

Surely this can't be what's intended? A 6 hour rabbit-hole of the internal minutia of `System.JSON`, and having to re-invent the wheel.

### Summary

How to convert `TJsonValue` into a JSON string?

### Bonus Reading

- [How do I convert a string to and from JSON with escaped/special characters using DBXJSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785963/)

Comment: In later Delphi versions, `ToJSON()` simply calls `ToBytes()` and then returns `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString()` with those bytes. You don't need a full JSON parser to undo any unwanted escaping, a simple loop over the JSON characters looking for `'\...'` escape sequences and replacing them with their unescaped counterparts will suffice.

Comment: Is there often such a substantial size difference using ToJSON that it causes performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to roll your own.

### First is the main function

```
class function TJsonHelper.ToJSON(const AJsonValue: TJsonValue): UnicodeString;
begin
{
    We have to do this most obvious thing ourselves, since Delphi gets it wrong.

    //WRONG: returns a human-readable string, but invalid JSON (e.g. does not convert CRLF into \r\n)
    Result := o.ToString;

    //INVALID: not defined in XE6
    Result := o.ToJSON;

    //WRONG: encodes everything above 128 into escaped \u0083
    SetLength(buffer, o.EstimatedByteSize);
    n := o.ToBytes(buffer, 0);
    SetLength(buffer, n);
}
    if AJsonValue = nil then
    begin
        Result := '';
        Exit;
    end;

    Result := PrettifyJsonValue(AJsonValue, '');
end;
```

### Priate Helper function

And then the actual guts are private in a **PrettifyJsonValue()** helper function:

```
type
    // Crack open the JsonString, and feast on the tasty string builder inside.    
    TJsonStringFriend = class(TJsonString) 
    end;

function PrettifyJsonValue(JsonValue: TJSONValue; Indentation: string=''): UnicodeString;
var
    jsonArray: TJSONArray;
    jsonObject: TJSONObject;
    pair: TJSONPair;
    i: Integer;
    s: UnicodeString;
    ch: WideChar;
    sKey, sValue: UnicodeString;
begin
    TConstraints.NotNull(JsonValue);

    if JsonValue is TJSONArray then
    begin
        jsonArray := JsonValue as TJSONArray;

        // Workaround a Delphi System.JSON bug where it cannot parse an empty array such as:
        //  "cities": [ ]
        if jsonArray.Count <= 0 then
        begin
            Result := '[]';
            Exit;
        end;

        Result := '['+ sLineBreak;
        for i := 0 to jsonArray.Count-1 do
        begin
            Result := Result + Indentation + '  ' + PrettifyJsonValue(jsonArray.Items[i], Indentation + '   ');
            if i < jsonArray.Count-1 then
                Result := Result + ',';
            Result := Result + sLineBreak;
        end;
        Result := Result + Indentation + ']';
    end
    else if JsonValue is TJSONObject then
    begin
        jsonObject := JsonValue as TJSONObject;
        Result := '{' + sLineBreak;
        for i := 0 to jsonObject.Count-1 do
        begin
            pair := jsonObject.Pairs[i];

            sKey := pair.JsonString.Value;
            sValue := PrettifyJsonValue(pair.JsonValue, Indentation+'   ');

            Result := Result + Indentation+'    "'+sKey+'": '+sValue;
            if i < jsonObject.Count-1 then
                Result := Result + ',';
            Result := Result + sLineBreak;
        end;
        Result := Result + Indentation + '}';
    end
    else if JsonValue.ClassType = TJsonString then //TJsonNumber descends from TJsonString
    begin
        // Delphi doesn't know how to emit valid JSON; we'll do it ourselves
        //SURPRISE: TJsonNumber descends from TJsonString. No, i'm not joking. Not even a little.
        Result := '"';
//      s := (JsonValue as TJsonString).ToString;
        s := TJsonStringFriend(JsonValue as TJsonString).FStrBuffer.ToString;
        for i := 1 to Length(s) do
        begin
            ch := s[i];
            case ch of
            '"': Result := Result + '\"';
            '\': Result := Result + '\\';
            '/': Result := Result + '\/';
            #$8: Result := Result + '\b';
            #$c: Result := Result + '\f';
            #$a: Result := Result + '\n';
            #$d: Result := Result + '\r';
            #$9: Result := Result + '\t';
            else
                if (ch < WideChar(32)) then
                    Result := Result + '\u'+IntToHex(Ord(ch), 4)
                else
                    Result := Result + ch;
            end;
        end;
        Result := Result+'"';
    end
    else
    begin
        // JsonValue is TJSONNumber, TJSONTrue, TJSONFalse, TJSONNull
        // I trust those know how to serialize themselves correctly into JSON
        Result := JsonValue.ToString;
    end;
end;
```

## Bonus Chatter

Delphi also has a well-known bug in it's parser, where it is unable to parse valid JSON.

You need to run your json string through a regex search-replace:

<kbd>[`(\[\[\s\]*\])(?=(?:\[^"\]|"\[^"\]*")*$)`](https://regexper.com/#%28%5C%5B%5B%5Cs%5D*%5C%5D%29%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%22%5D%7C%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29*%24%29)</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>`[]`</kbd>